# Connecting to docker container using "container ip"

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I am running docker on mac. I would like to connect to docker container using its ip (not the ip of the virtual box machine). The reason is spark driver registers itself with container ip "172.17.0.2" and the client running from mac tries to connect to this address. Is there a way to connect to 172.17.0.2 from macbook with ip 192.168.99.1.

```
ravis-MacBook-Pro:datadir raviramadoss$ ifconfig | grep inet
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    inet6 fe80::22c9:d0ff:fec3:ab3b%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
    inet 172.20.10.2 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 172.20.10.15
    inet6 fe80::2c59:11ff:fe77:f5a6%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9
    inet6 fe80::8f9:68c0:9430:41eb%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb
    inet6 fdd6:aa86:393a:d244:8f9:68c0:9430:41eb prefixlen 64
    inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
    inet6 fe80::4fc0:193a:6763:2e97%utun1 prefixlen 64 scooped 0x14
```

Virtual box ip

```
ravis-MacBook-Pro:sbin raviramadoss$ docker-machine ip
192.168.99.100
```

container

```
[raviramadoss@karaba logs]$ ifconfig | grep inet
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 Scope:Link
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Ravi R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Docker Networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/). The IP you see inside the Container is the private IP iside the docker network.

The only (good) way to access the container to [publish a port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/publish-or-expose-port-p-expose) of the container and access it via VM-IP:published-container-port. Alternatively you can use the option `--net=host` to use the docker hosts netwok interface directly but this is not recommended.

Comment: I am using VM-IP:published-container-port method. But in this case, I don't have control over the ip. The ip is registered with container ip. So I am forced to access the container directly. Are there any samples to use -net=host. I'm sorry, unable to find any.

Comment: where do you register the container exaclty? and why do you need control over the IP? just write `docker run --net host someImage`

Comment: This did solve the problem at hand. But another one creeped up. Now the hostname of my container is the same as my docker machine name and it resolves to 127.0.0.1!!

Comment: This is the intended behaviour ;-) Do i get you right you have a Mac (IP_M) which runs a VM (IP_VM) which runs a Container (IP_C) and you want to make calls from the container to some web API with the IP Adress of IP_M?

Comment: It is the opposite. I wanted to connect to a process running in container (IP_C) from (IP_M). But all is well now with --net host command. I changed the hosts file and everything looks good. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Which Docker app are you using? AFAIK with Docker for Mac beta you can not do this right now:

> Unfortunately, due to limtations in OSX, we’re unable to route traffic
>   to containers, and from containers back to the host.

If you want the behavior to be more consistent with "native" Docker, you may want to explore a Vagrant host or similar solution.

Comment: After using the --net=host command, I was able to attach the container tot he host network. I think this just makes the docker container behave like a virtual box machine.