# Connect to docker using IP instead of localhost

Tags: docker

I'm running a docker container (running a cloudera image in which I can't modify the networks settings) in my windows 10 pc and I want to connect to it from my browser using the assigned IP (i.e. 172.17.0.2) instead of localhost.
Is there a way to do it? How?

(I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872328/connecting-to-docker-container-using-container-ip)  and I've tried to use the --net=host option but the docker0 IP assigned is still 172.17.0.1.)

Below the "ifconfig" output:

```
[root@quickstart /]# ifconfig
cni0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6A:6A:D3:6A:CB:82
      inet addr:10.1.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::686a:d3ff:fe6a:cb82/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12920 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:884288 (863.5 KiB)  TX bytes:3946860 (3.7 MiB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:65:2D:65:6C
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:65ff:fe2d:656c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:10104 (9.8 KiB)  TX bytes:185370 (181.0 KiB)

docker_gwbridge Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:FF:2D:D6:CD
      inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:ffff:fe2d:d6cd/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:339368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:339368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:63421670 (60.4 MiB)  TX bytes:63421670 (60.4 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:50:00:00:00:01
      inet addr:192.168.65.3  Bcast:192.168.65.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
      inet6 addr: fe80::50:ff:fe00:1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:131024 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:76313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:157839066 (150.5 MiB)  TX bytes:8175888 (7.7 MiB)

hvint0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5D:CD:11:09
      inet addr:10.0.75.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fecd:1109/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:257 errors:0 dropped:53 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:21003 (20.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1358 (1.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:339368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:339368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:63421670 (60.4 MiB)  TX bytes:63421670 (60.4 MiB)

veth535bb6e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:E5:EC:F3:76:BC
      inet6 addr: fe80::14e5:ecff:fef3:76bc/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:2318 (2.2 KiB)

vethc291b186 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:3A:FE:9F:40:7A
      inet6 addr: fe80::703a:feff:fe9f:407a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6441 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:518245 (506.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1959228 (1.8 MiB)

vethc0969f7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F2:9E:81:04:9B:69
      inet6 addr: fe80::f09e:81ff:fe04:9b69/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:74394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:129442 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:8037110 (7.6 MiB)  TX bytes:157544590 (150.2 MiB)

vethdba5d116 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 26:D1:6D:9B:28:8E
      inet6 addr: fe80::24d1:6dff:fe9b:288e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:516002 (503.9 KiB)  TX bytes:1960294 (1.8 MiB)

vethf1ece51f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:A3:6A:C9:70:37
      inet6 addr: fe80::70a3:6aff:fec9:7037/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:30921 (30.1 KiB)  TX bytes:34060 (33.2 KiB)
```

Comment: --net=host option does not work on Windows or Mac, you should expose the service port and then you could connect to it, guide here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: `docker0` is not a container, this is a bridge network created by Docker, this will always be eg. `172.17.0.1` / `172.18.0.1` etc. (in case of more networks) because this is your host which acts as a gateway. Now a container is going to get next assignable IP address from that subnet which is going to be `172.17.0.2`. Run a container and ping `172.17.0.2`, you should get a response. This address should be resolvable from your host, if it's not resolvable from another host in your network this is due firewall restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean by `connect to it from my browser`, could you first make clear your aims?

Comment: @atline: I need to connect to the docker's container using the browser installed locally in my PC. Now I can reach the Claudera's control panel with "localhost:<port>" but I need to use the docker's IP (172.18.0.1:<port>).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have some misunderstanding for docker network.

Docker use `veth pair` as the default bridge technology to communicate between host & container, see next diagram:

[image: https://img-blog.csdn.net/20180820162528508?watermark/2/text/aHR0cHM6Ly9ibG9nLmNzZG4ubmV0L3hid19saW51eDEyMw==/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70]

So, `172.17.0.1` is just a bridge between your host's network card & containers' network card, you couldn't use it direclty. Meanwhile, you should not use container's ip from your host's browser to visit it as it's in a private network which setup by docker, what you could do is use `-p` to publish your internal network service to external.

And, when you visit `localhost`, it in fact just visit host's network, and docker use iptables to pass your network traffic to container's port through `docker0` bridge. So, for your case, if you do not want to use `localhost`, then you could use host's ip instead, that is `192.168.65.3` in your case.

Comment: Your diagram saved my job lol